# Generate Pod files issue after updating the react native version 0.59 to 0.60

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have updated the react-native version `0.59.9` to `0.60.5`.

Before version:

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9",
```

After updating the version:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
```

After updating the version, in `iOS` directory, can not see the pod file.
So I have run the following command to generate the `pod` file.

```
pod init
pod install
```

After applying the command I can see my pod file like below.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Base' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Base

  target 'BaseTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

But when we create a new project then we can get following pod file by default with pods.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'Temp' do
  # Pods for Temp
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'TempTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'Temp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for Temp-tvOS

  target 'Temp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

So, If I want to create the pod file after updating the version of react-native then, How can we create the pod file like default one?